# I installed android studio 3.1.2 and it showing an error

Tags: android, android-studio

In installed android studio 3.1.2 and it showing the following error.

C:\Users\ADC-2\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication5\app\src\main\res\values\colors.xml:6:40: Error: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.

color.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!--
/*
 ** Copyright 2016, The Android Open Source Project
 **
 ** Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 ** you may not use this file except in
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have updated Android studio and opened the existing project, try selecting the Invalidate Caches/ Restart option from the file menu option in Android studio. If u still face the issue then open the project location folder, delete .idea and .impl files and reopen the project in Android studio. I hope this should help you.

Comment: I created a new project in the newer version of Android studio

Comment: I tried creating the new project with the same version of Android studio, but I didn’t face any issues.